# PHP Date format day of week

Tags: php, mysql, date

Im my slq statement I have this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%jS %M %Y') AS endDate
```

I expect the date to come out like `20th February 2017` but instead I get `jS February 2017`.

The jS isnt working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use it as `%D`, not `%jS`

```
DATE_FORMAT(end_date,'%D %M %Y') AS endDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `mysql` `DATE_FORMAT` function, so you have to use the patter `%D`

From [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp):

> %D Day of month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, �)

Answer (score 0):

You should use %D instead of %jS !
As stated here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp